# What is the meaning of sending the "class" message to an instance of a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-login

In the Facebook login code at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced, they ask us to execute following sequence

1. Declare The view that will be displayed to be of "FBSDKLoginButton" class through storyboard.
2. Execute following line in the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

   ```
   [FBSDKLoginButton class];
   ```

What is the meaning of sending a "class" message to an object?

Comment: It says right before the picture: "This loads `FBSDKLoginButton` before the view displays"

Comment: Thank.  But I don't see a method called class in their source code?  Is it a generic Objective-C thing?  If yes, can you give me some more details?  For e.g: Is this always needed when you set a view to be a "custom class"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is used to call the `initialize` method of the `FBSDKLoginButton`. The `+(void)initialize` is a method that is called before any instance of a class is initialised. Its called just once. `[FBSDKLoginButton class]` is used to trigger the `initialize` method to be called.

Comment: Thanks, Pradeep.  Is this a generic Objective-C thing?  I.e whenever you call [XXX class], it calls the initialize method?  What is the difference between calling this vs doing an [[XXX alloc] init] ?

Comment: When you call [XXX class] no instance of that class is created although the class object itself gets initialized. But when you call [XXX alloc] init] an instance of that class is also created along with the class object being initialized if it was not already done. Basically the `initialize` can be loosely treated as a init for a class. Its used to initialize any class properties that you might have in the class. Note that its called just once and not every time an instance is created.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot